# What Algorithm is Adrian relying on?

Tags: the-good-fight

In *The Good Fight* episode 2 - *First Week*. when Adrian Boseman is trying to get the funding to cover the Class Action he's discussing it with 2 guys where one is on a laptop. the guy on the laptop suggests that they don't take on the Class Action not because the case was bad because of the Judge.

They mention that what the guy with the laptop is doing is running stuff though an Algorithm and when he suggests they don't pressure the Class Action Adrian asks if the Algorithm also accounts that he is

> a fucken good laywer

which he repeats (without the swear which he got told off for) when he mentions that he can get the Judge changed

But what is this Algorithm? is it determining if they can win or what their profit margin would be like regardless if they won or lost? (because there didn't seem to be much of a fallout after they lost the Dismissal, rather just Maia telling Diane that she hates loosing and Diane telling her that people can be telling the truth and lying at the same time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But what is this Algorithm? is it determining if they can win or what their profit margin would be like regardless if they won or lost?

Essentially...yes.

There are algorithms used by Litigation Finance companies that allege to be able to calculate such things...but their capacities and actual usage are debatable.

I found this article at [The New Yorker](http://www.newyorker.com/business/currency/what-litigation-finance-is-really-about) which goes into the concept.

> Using an algorithm to calculate the likelihood that a lawsuit will succeed, the company then invests in cases it deems promising. If a plaintiff it has funded prevails, Legalist [a LF startup] takes a percentage of the winnings—usually between twenty-five and thirty per cent. The algorithm considers, among other things, the size of the presiding judge’s caseload, which is an indicator of how long a trial will take, and the judge’s past decisions, which is an indicator of how he or she might rule.